# Chopping first 16 characters using SED

Tags: command-line, tools

I am using a SED command to try chop lines down. I am currently trying to get the first 16 characters to chop from a text file (line by line)

Examples lines:

```
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  ALASTAIR-MUNRO    
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  ANDREWATKINSON    
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  ANDY-KAYE         
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  ANDYTURNER        
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CAD-SPARE2        
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CAD-SPARE3        
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CADTEMP1          
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CARLWALKER        
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CAROLEGIBBONS     
psinfo -s -c   psinfo -s -c  CHRIS-SMITH
```

I am trying to chop the first lot of `PSinfo -s -c` out and then convert this into a separate txt

This is what I've got which isn't working (below) Any ideas?

```
BIN\sed -e 's/^\(.\{60\}\).*/\16/' Working\Hostnames3.txt > Working\Hostnames4.txt
```

Comment: `sed 's/.\{16\}//'` - but your question doesn't seem to be Ubuntu related

Comment: Start by writing your file paths properly. The separator on Linux is `/`, not `\\`.

Comment: Can you advice on a decent method to tidy this line up? I want it to pickup hostname.txt, chop the first 16 characters (thus removing the repeat)

Comment: Voting to close this as OT since based on comments you appear to be running (an unknown version of) sed from inside a Windows batch script - this has nothing to do with Ubuntu so far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

An easy and economical method to accomplish this is:

```
cut -c 16- hostname.txt > altered_hostname.txt
```

The magic section of this simple `cut` command is in these 2 options:

```
-c,   --characters=LIST
       select only these characters
 N-    from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line
```

Comment: Will that run the CUT -16 against all lines in the document?

Comment: Certainly will...

Comment: (+1):  `cut -c 17-` ?

Comment: @JJoao You would think so wouldn't you? But testing shows that 16 is the magic number. Oddly enough the command adds an extra blank line at the end of the series which I have not managed to work out yet...

Comment: @andrew.46, from the example presented, the PO probably means "removeing 15 char";  Anyway: `cut -c 16- ` ⇔ "chopping 15".

Comment: @andrew.46, > adds an extra blank line : it seems perfect for me. (It is common the unix tools to add a `\n` if the input's last line has no `\n`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command (awk)

```
awk '{sub(".*" $3 FS,"")}1' Working/Hostnames3.txt > Working/Hostnames4.txt
```

to remove first three fields from the input file
(by my understanding this is what you need)
P.S. Here is example of execution of above script:

```
# cat in
a b c d
aa bb cc dd
a1 b1 c1 d1

# awk '{sub(".*" $3 FS,"")}1' in >out
# cat out
d
dd
d1
```

Comment: I need it to remove the first 15, can i just apply $3 to $15, assuming its the same principal?

Comment: Right, @KyleCrowther. But do not forget I talk (and awk work with) fields, not characters. Please exec the command above and check the result

Comment: Doesnt like it. Hostname4 output file empty.

Comment: I just need it to trim each line by 15 characters. Its confusing why its duplicating the beginning anyway is the command im running before hand = BIN\sed 's#'\\#' psinfo -s -c  #g' Working\Hostnames2.txt > Working\Hostnames3.txt

Comment: What is the delimiter in your input file?

Comment: Sorry, not following - im new to this. My whole file as below:

Comment: rem @echo off


REM ** GET LIST OF PCS ON NETWORK **
NET VIEW > Working\Netview.txt
BIN\sed -e 's/^\(.\{20\}\).*/\1/' Working\Netview.txt > Working\Hostnames.txt  

REM ** NOW TRIM DOWN TO JUST COMPUTER NAMES **
BIN\fgrep -e \\ Working\Hostnames.txt  > "Working\Hostnames2.txt" 
 
BIN\sed 's#'\\#' psinfo -s -c  #g' Working\Hostnames2.txt > Working\Hostnames3.txt

REM Works until here

PAUSE

  
BIN\sed -e 's/^\(.\{60\}\).*/\16/' Working\Hostnames3.txt > Working\Hostnames4.txt

Comment: I am running a netview to check current PC's, Its then trimming the file to a list of \\%hostnames% then im then getting it to write me a new .txt file which adds "PSInfo*** to the lines so i get a file with all the psinfo \\%hostname% lines so i can run a full scan for all software on all machines via automation

Comment: @KyleCrowther, please add this in to your question. Delimiter is a character (or string) with separate fields. For example comma delimited files.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach : get the last `psinfo ....` with grep:

```
grep -Po '.*\Kpsinfo.*'
```